# Doctrine Orm lazy load with group by

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I have the following situation:

```
    /**
     * @Entity 
     * @Table(name="users")
     */

    class Users{

        /**
         *
         * @Id  @Column(type="integer")
         * @GeneratedValue
         */
        protected $id_user;

        /**
         * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Items",mappedBy="user")
         */
        private $items;

//this method sould return distinct items by name or group by name
public function getItems(){
return $this->items;
}
    }



       /**
     * @Entity 
     * @Table(name="items")
     */

class Items{

    /**
     *
     * @Id  @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id_item;

   /**
     *
     * @Id  @Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

       /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User",inversedBy="items")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user" ,onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

In my view i send an $UserEntity, my problem is that i want to display only items that have unique name.
So If i do $items=$userEntity->getItems(); i receive all user items, not only unique one.

How can i solve this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select distinct with DQL should do the trick